# Using Tone.js with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, tone.js

Tone.js has a data type that wraps microphone input - `UserMedia` ([docs](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/13.8.25/UserMedia), [src](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/blob/dev/Tone/source/UserMedia.ts#L43)), but I have not been able to figure out how to connect the wrapped stream to a web audio API `MediaRecorder` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder)).

If I understand `MediaRecorder` correctly, its constructor takes a `MediaStream` - but the tone.js UserMedia wrapper does not expose this.

Can Tone.js `UserMedia` be used in combination with the `MediaRecorder` API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tone.js [feature request #644](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/644) implements this, by adding a `Recorder` class that wraps `MediaRecorder`.